# Sorting a select dropdown via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select drop down which needs to be sorted by alphabetical order.
My dropdown is built dynamically via jQuery and it gets the data from a PHP response.

This is the code to build the dropdown

```
//- Create an array of the acceptable values for this udf (tags)
var array = $('input[name=hidden-tags]').val().split(',');

var dropdown = "";

dropdown += "<option disabled selected>Valid options</option>";

$.each(array,function(i){
   dropdown += "<option value='"+array [i]+"'>"+ array[i] +"</option>";       
});

//- Add in validation list to the dropdown
$("#autofix-dropdown").html(dropdown);
```

The hidden-tags input is populated with the 'tags' part of this data

```
[{"_id":{"$id":"56d42175b23eec3f1a8b4567"},
"agency_id":"01721487",
"rule_name":"UDF 1",
"rule_desc":"...",  
"rule_type":"account",
"vali_field":"udf_1",
"vali_type":"validation_list",
"allow_blank":"allow_blank",
"folder":"5637503fb23eec5a110fe4b4",
"AutoFix":{"kbbb":[""],"kathryn pascoe":["kathryn pascoe"]},
"tags":["kbbb","test","kathryn pascoe","mabel chan"],
"accounts":["SIT0001","SIT0002","SIT0003","NCC0001","NCC0002","NCC0003","NCC0004"]}]
```

I can't order it in Mongo which is the database I am using because this is used elsewhere where it doesn't need to be sorted. I need to sort it within jQuery.

Comment: Wouldn't `array.sort()` before your `$.each(array..` do exactly what you need?

Comment: @apokryfos Perfect, didn't even think about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

> The `sort()` method sorts the items of an array.

```js
/* just for the demo, initial the data like the ajax do */
var tags = ["kbbb","test","kathryn pascoe","mabel chan"];
$('input[name=hidden-tags]').val(tags.join(','));


//- Create an array of the acceptable values for this udf (tags)
var array = $('input[name=hidden-tags]').val().split(',');
console.log(array);
array = array.sort();
console.log(array);

var dropdown = "";

dropdown += "<option disabled selected>Valid options</option>";

$.each(array,function(i){
   dropdown += "<option value='"+array [i]+"'>"+ array[i] +"</option>";       
});

//- Add in validation list to the dropdown
$("#autofix-dropdown").html(dropdown);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="hidden-tags" />
<select id="autofix-dropdown"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks Mosh, someone has already gave me this solution but yes this did work.